How can I split a line at the cursor position in VS Code, but keep the cursor in the original position after pressing Enter?
For example, if I have:
abc|de

(where | represents the cursor position)
After pressing Enter, I want it to look like this:
abc|
de

Notice that the cursor remains in the original position. How can I achieve this in Visual Studio Code?

The key bind that you are looking for is called lineBreakInsert and is included in Visual Studio Code, however by default it is not bound to any keys. To bind it, go to the shortcut menu with Ctrl+k Ctrl+s then search for lineBreakInsert. Right click and press "Add Keybinding..." and put whatever combination you want. (I would do Ctrl+Shift+Enter since I don't use it often but that's just me)
You also want to make sure your key bind doesn't interfere with other function of VSCode so you should also set the When clause to editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly so that it is only available in the editor.
It is also possible to set up custom shortcuts using the keybindings.json file where you can string together multiple commands, for more info you can look here.
